# Match Urls in results of api call

Tags: php, laravel, api, guzzle

I have an api call that amongst it has Url's that are recalled in it's returned JSON.

I need to find those returned urls that have in them the string used for the original get request and have statuses of 200. I tried using the strpos method, but that didn't seem to work.

```
public function getCompanyData() {
    $client = new Client();
    $response = $client->request('GET', 'https://api.github.com/orgs/fakename');
    $statusCode = $response->getStatusCode();
    $body = $response->getBody()->getContents();

    $confirmed = strpos($body,'api.github.com/orgs/fakename');
    if($statusCode === 200 && $confirmed !== false) { 
        return $body; 
    }
    else {
        return $statusCode." Error";
    }
}
```

Returned JSON -

```
{
  "login": "fakename",
  "id": 1214096,
  "node_id": "***=",
  "url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/fakename",
  "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/fakename/repos",
  "events_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/fakename/events",
  "hooks_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/fakename/hooks",
  "issues_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/fakename/issues",
  "members_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/fakename/members{/member}",
  "public_members_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/fakename/public_members{/member}",
  "avatar_url": "https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/****?v=4",
  "description": "",
  "name": "fakename",
  "company": null,
  "blog": "fakename.com",
  "location": null,
  "email": null,
  "twitter_username": null,
  "is_verified": false,
  "has_organization_projects": true,
  "has_repository_projects": true,
  "public_repos": 41,
  "public_gists": 0,
  "followers": 0,
  "following": 0,
  "html_url": "https://github.com/fakename",
  "created_at": "2011-11-22T21:48:43Z",
  "updated_at": "2020-09-11T23:05:04Z"
}
```

Comment: You need to do this in your PHP or in your javascript?

Comment: Also, is this JSON the value you get from calling `$client->request('GET', 'https://api.github.com/orgs/fakename');`, or is it the value `getCompanyData` returns?

Comment: @WesleySmith This get request is in my controller so, in php. But I will eventually call the data to the client side. 

The JSON is from the getCompanyData return. When I simply return $body, this is the JSON I get back

Comment: Once I indentify the matching JSON urls that are status 200, I will printout the keys and values within them

Comment: I guess im confused because you're calling `$client->request('GET', 'https://api.github.com/orgs/fakename');` which seems to return a json value where the `url` value is the url that was called which seems to indicate that if you checked for `'api.github.com/orgs/fakename'` (the url that was called) the check would _always_ return true. What am I missing here?

Comment: @WesleySmith Pardon me. I'm trying to follow all urls containing "api.github.com/orgs/fakename" in the path, and for responses with a 200 status code, retrieve and display all 'id' keys/values in the response objects.

Where I retrieve those urls is from the get request

Comment: But the call to `$client->request` is hard coded to go to `'https://api.github.com/orgs/fakename'` and the response will include the `"url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/fakename",` (ie the url that was called) so the response is _always_ going to contain `'api.github.com/orgs/fakename'` because _thats the url it always calls_

Comment: If the url being called was dynamic and passed to `getCompanyData` and used for `client->request`, then you were checking for a specific url, I could understand, but if the url is hard coded like this, the response will always be the same, so the check will always be the same. I feel like there's something missing here

Comment: @WesleySmith You're right, I see what you're saying now. I was just trying to figure out how to call those urls in the json all at once (if those urls contained that string as part of the url, as the way to identify them) and then query their keys/values.

Comment: I guess I will have to query them all, one at a time?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to call 'https://api.github.com/orgs/fakename', get its json response, loop over the properties of that response and for every property that is a url containing 'https://api.github.com/orgs/fakename', make a call to that endpoint and get its data? Like make calls to the urls for `repos_url`, `events_url`, `hooks_url`, etc...?

Comment: @WesleySmith That's exactly what I am trying to accomplish (if they have a statusCode of 200)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be as follows:

```
<?php

class SomeClass
{
    /**
     * @var int The status code of the last http request
     */
    private $statusCode;

    /**
     * Get an array of decoded data from the given url.
     * @param $url
     * @return array
     */
    public function getDataFromUrl($url) {
        $client           = new Client();
        $response         = $client->request('GET', $url);
        $this->statusCode = $response->getStatusCode();
        $body             = $response->getBody()->getContents();
        return $this->statusCode === 200 ? json_decode($body, true) : [];
    }

    /**
     * Get all data for a given organization including nested ancillary data
     * @param string $orgName
     * @return array
     */
    public function getCompanyData($orgName) {
        $mainUrl = "https://api.github.com/orgs/$orgName";
        $mainData = $this->getDataFromUrl($mainUrl);
        if ($mainData && $this->statusCode === 200) {
            $ancillaryUrls = $this->getAncillaryUrlsFromData($mainData, $orgName);
            foreach ($ancillaryUrls as $property => $url) {
                $ancillaryData = $this->getDataFromUrl($url);
                $mainData[$property] = $ancillaryData;
            }
        }
        return $mainData;
    }

    /**
     * Get a JSON string containing all data for a given organization including nested ancillary data
     * @param string $orgName
     * @return array|mixed
     */
    public function getCompanyDataAsJson($orgName) {
        return json_encode($this->getCompanyData($orgName));
    }

    /**
     * From the provided array of data, return an new array containing the ancillary urls
     * which also need to be requested
     * @param array $data
     * @param string $orgName
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAncillaryUrlsFromData($data, $orgName) {
        $urls = [];
        if (is_array($data)) {
            $targetUrl = "api.github.com/orgs/$orgName";
            foreach ($data as $property => $value) {
                // if property has '_url' and value is like our url, add it to our array of urls
                if (strpos($property, '_url') !== false && strpos($value, $targetUrl) !== false) {
                    $cleanProp = str_replace('_url', '', $property);
                    $urls[$cleanProp] = $targetUrl;
                }
            }
        }
        return $urls;
    }
}
```

Now, if you want the result as an array, you can call:

```
$someClass   = new SomeClass();
$arrayOfData = $someClass->getCompanyData('fakename');
```

Or, if you want the result as a JSON string, you can call:

```
$someClass = new SomeClass();
$jsonData  = $someClass->getCompanyDataAsJson('fakename');
```

And the response will have the following keys (in addition to the original main data) `"repos", "events", "hooks", "issues", "members", "public_members"`  all filled with the responses from their individual calls.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll be deconstructing this for awhile. 